# Show that $f(x, y): \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R, (x,y)\to e^{x^2+y^2}$ has a isolated local extremum

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Show that $f(x, y): \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R, (x,y)\to e^{x^2+y^2}$ has a isolated local extremum.

My idea: I think I have to find critical points, where the function is $0$, but it never gets $0$, so which are the points and how to find? Did also Hesse Matrix.

Comment: To @math3290495 : How do you define a critical point?

Comment: Critical points are not found where the function is zero, but where the derivative of the function is zero.

Comment: You have the correct idea of finding critical points. Hessian is related, but to identify a local extremum, you should use the Jacobian instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Find critical point(s), i.e. solve this system:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0, \\\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0.$$

The resulting pair(s) of values $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2),...$ can be substituted into the second derivates

$$A=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}, \space B=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y}, \space C=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}. $$

Depending on the expression $\space AC-B^2 \space$ it can be decided whether an extreme value exists...

**Figure:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any calculus for this question. The function's value is $1$ at the origin and strictly greater everywhere else, so the origin is an isolated local extremum. There are no other extrema since at any point other than the origin the function is clearly increasing when you move radially away from the origin.

Comment: ok so the isolated local extremum is in point (0,1)?

Comment: you say the isolated extremum is in origin but the origin is (0,0)?but the isolated local extremum is in point (0,1)? can you please explain?

Comment: The local extremum is at $(0,0,1)$, the point above the origin $(0,0)$ in the domain.  See the picture in @AntonVrdoljak 's answer.

Comment: ok i understood

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x,y)=e^{x^2+y^2}$ has extremum at the points where $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ has the extremum. It is easy to see that $g$ has minimum value $0$ at $(0,0)$ which implies that $f=e^g$ has minimum at $(0,0)$ and $f_{min}=e^0=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Hessian, you need to first find the Jacobian. Then you set it to zero to find the local extremum. The Hessian matrix is something you need for telling whether it is min or max.